Assigning a Percentile Range based off a Product/Retailors Revenu
I'm dealing with quite a puzzle at work within Pbi that I/ChatGPT/Co-pilot can't figure out.
I created a summary table of this dummy data set to showcase what I'm trying to do (image attached)

I'm trying to create a table visual in PowerBI that has a column added called "Percentile Range" which assigns a Percentile range of sales based off the product by retailor.
For example, since Staples had the highest revenue for Iphone sales, the value in this added column would be "90th Percentile". While ATT (who had the lowest sales) would output a value that says "10th Percentile".
I need to do this for each individual product types (aka Ipad sales would have it's own percentile range because it's different from Iphone)
If anyone can help me figure out how to isolate revenue to specific product I would greatly appreciate it thanks!
Here's what I tried so far, but this formula assigns the percentile range based off the total revenue of all products.
Percentile Range Measure = 
VAR TotalRev = SUM(DummyData[Revenue]) //Sums Revenue of OG dummy data that has spend of individual transactions

//Percentile range based off summary table and column "TotalRev" that is SUM(DummyData[Revenue])

VAR Percentile90 = PERCENTILEX.INC(RevSummaryTable, [TotalRev], 0.9)
VAR Percentile75 = PERCENTILEX.INC(RevSummaryTable, [TotalRev], 0.75)
VAR Percentile50 = PERCENTILEX.INC(RevSummaryTable, [TotalRev], 0.5)
VAR Percentile10 = PERCENTILEX.INC(RevSummaryTable, [TotalRev], 0.1)


RETURN
    IF(TotalRev >= Percentile90, "90th Percentile",
    IF(TotalRev >= Percentile75, "75th Percentile",
    IF(TotalRev >= Percentile50, "Middle Range",
    IF(TotalRev >= Percentile10, "10th Percentile", "Bottom Percentile")))


Close. Your TotalRev variable should be returning a Filtered table, and the PERCENTILEX expression should refer to a column in that table.
Try:
Percentile Range Measure = 
   VAR filteredTable = FILTER('Table','Table'[Product]=EARLIER([Product]))

   VAR Percentile90 = PERCENTILEX.INC(filteredTable, [Revenue], 0.9)
   VAR Percentile75 = PERCENTILEX.INC(filteredTable, [Revenue], 0.75)
   VAR Percentile50 = PERCENTILEX.INC(filteredTable, [Revenue], 0.5)
   VAR Percentile10 = PERCENTILEX.INC(filteredTable, [Revenue], 0.1)


RETURN
    IF([Revenue] >= Percentile90,"90th Percentile",
    IF([Revenue]>=Percentile75,"75th Percentile",
    IF([Revenue]>= Percentile50,"Middle Range",
    if([Revenue]>=Percentile10,"10th Percentile","Bottom Percentile"))))

But I think ATT/iPhone should return "Bottom Percentile" as the 10th percentile is a higher number ($358,156 vs $241,100)

